# git ssh_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort

Tags: git, github

Today I fork a project into my github from https://github.com/bhlx3lyx7/incubator-griffin/tree/master. When I use git clone command like this: **git clone git@github.com:ahutsunshine/incubator-griffin.git measure-json**.A big problem has come up.The following photo is the problem.Do you have some advice to solve it ? 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using this in windows, I guess?

Comment: yes,I am using windows.Have you ever been in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks you all.Now I have solved this problem.The key to the problem is **git url(ssh or https)**.

If you use clone with ssh,like  git@github.com:apache/incubator-griffin.git,it will be wrong.
[image]

However,if you use clone with https,like https://github.com/apache/incubator-griffin.git,it will clone successfully.

[image]

After reviewing related document，I find they currently recommend HTTPS because it is the easiest to set up on the widest range of networks and platforms, and by users who are new to all this.

1. HTTPS is less likely to be blocked by a firewall.

   https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/

   [image]
2. An HTTPS connection allows credential.helper to cache your password.

   https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is nothing to do with git first. Its SSH identification failure. First, check your environment.

This is local environment issue. The error clearly says `no such file or directory.`

Find this file `key_load_public`. The key file is missing, you need to add the key file if its missing.